# Flexbox Order and Tabbing Navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to use **display: flex** to change the **order** of divs with *line* class, but I'd like to maintain this TAB navigation order: A → B → C → D.

As you can see in the snippets, the first example works fine (the DOM sequence is the same of the Order), but in the second example the tab follow the DOM sequence.

Any chance without using javascript?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.line {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.line span {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Tabbing navigation OK
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" style="order: 1;"><input value="A"><span>1st div - Order: 1</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 2;"><input value="B"><span>2nd div - Order: 2</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 3;"><input value="C"><span>3rd div - Order: 3</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 4;"><input value="D"><span>4th div - Order: 4</span></div>
</div>

<h2>
  Tabbing navigation KO
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" style="order: 1;"><input value="A"><span>1st div - Order: 1</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 4;"><input value="C"><span>2nd div - Order: 4</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 3;"><input value="C"><span>3rd div - Order: 3</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 2;"><input value="B"><span>4th div - Order: 2</span></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/054hua3r/).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use `tabindex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `tabindex` html attribute

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.line {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.line span {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Tabbing navigation OK
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" style="order: 1;"><input value="A"><span>1st div - Order: 1</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 2;"><input value="B"><span>2nd div - Order: 2</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 3;"><input value="C"><span>3rd div - Order: 3</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 4;"><input value="D"><span>4th div - Order: 4</span></div>
</div>

<h2>
  Tabbing navigation KO
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" style="order: 1;"><input value="A" tabindex="1"><span>1st div - Order: 1</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 4;"><input value="C" tabindex="4"><span>2nd div - Order: 4</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 3;"><input value="C" tabindex="3"><span>3rd div - Order: 3</span></div>
  <div class="line" style="order: 2;"><input value="B" tabindex="2"><span>4th div - Order: 2</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was looking for something that didn't use the tabindex, but seems to be necessary...

Comment: @Alex pretty sure it's the only way if you don't want to use JS. CSS is for display only, so you can't do it with CSS. What's wrong with tabindex?

Comment: In the real case in each div.line there are a lot of elements, not only an input like in the example, and I would not bind us to tabindex. But I think too that this is the only way... :) Thank you!

Comment: If these are the only elements on the page to be tabbed to using tabindex in this way works, but otherwise is improper use of tabindex. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

Answer (score 11):

There is no currently good way to change the visual order via css whether by utilizing flex or floating the content and still maintain the tab order.

Assigning the tabindex attribute when there are many other fields on the page incurs a maintenance issue that shouldn't be present. Opera supposedly assigns tab index as items flow on the page, no other browsers currently do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the tab order simply add tabindex="x" to your divs.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp