# Ordering components in angular

Tags: angular

I need to sort components dynamically in the following template

```
<div class="orderList">
    <componentA></componentA>
    <componentB></componentB>
    <componentC></componentC>
</div>
```

by the object like

```
orders: {
    componentA: 2,
    componentB: 3,
    componentC: 1
}
```

So I expect to see componentC at first then componentA and finally componentB?

**Notes:** components are more than three

Comment: What not order them in your root component right away? Please give us more context.

Comment: Do you wish to render them on certain order?

Comment: @Christopher after ordering I need, componentC comes at first and then componentA and then componentB

Comment: Use ng-repeat to render and rerender them

Comment: If you add components like demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468, then you just need to reorder the component types in an array.

Comment: thank you @GünterZöchbauer. I have added an answer from your helpful comment. but I think there could be an easier answer to this simple question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think its better to use `css flex` for this issue because of better performance at least. how do you think?

Comment: @fingerpich I'd expect this to be complicated with CSS. If it's only 3 components and the order doesn't change, then I would just hardcode the order in HTML, if it's more components and the order does actually change, then I find it easiest to reorder an array and let `*ngFor` do the rest. I don't know a good way to sort for example 25+ elements with flex in arbitrary order, but CSS isn't my strong side ;-)

Comment: Theoretically they could be sorted in CSS, but dynamically enabling them for the sake of lazy loading wouldn't be easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using CSS flex order property

```
<div style="display:flex;">
   <componentA [style.order]="orders.componentA"></componentA>
   <componentB [style.order]="orders.componentB"></componentB>
   <componentC [style.order]="orders.componentC"></componentC>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to add, that in order to change direction u can use ```display:flex; flex-direction: column;``` (By default child components are in a row)

Comment: You have to be careful with accessibility with this one. Tabbing order has to be intuitive for users with visual disabilities. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308934/flexbox-order-and-tabbing-navigation

Answer (score 1):

As @GünterZöchbauer suggested in comments this answer uses `ngComponentOutlet` to sort components dynamically

```
<ng-container 
    *ngFor="item in sortedComponent" 
    *ngComponentOutlet="item.component">
</ng-container>

sortedComponent = [
    {index: 4, component: 'componentA'},
    {index: 5, component: 'componentB'},
    {index: 2, component: 'componentC'},
].sort((a, b) => a.index > b.index)
```

Comment: what is `component` in `item.component`? Is it a component directive?

Comment: item.component is component name that you have defined it.

Comment: when you have created the component's object then why there is a need to again add component class name. This looks illogical

Comment: let say you have a component class as `myComponent`, then how it would be called? According to you (what I understand) `item.myComponent`, right

Comment: I just have updated the answer and add more details about what I did

Comment: @fingerpich to be clear, you cannot use strings as your component. You need to pass the type of the component. The actual usage of ngComponentOutlet is much more complex than this. This answer gives a better overview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522759/angular-4-using-ngcomponentoutlet-to-display-dynamically-changing-contentchildre

Comment: if you had defined those components it will work. see the [document](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet), I tested it and it worked.